# What fitting do I need to ground EMT at my residential electrical panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, conduit

I know EMT can be used as its own grounding path, and no separate grounding ("green" or bare) conductor is required within the conduit, but what fitting do I need at the panel to complete the grounding path?  Is a grounded bushing required for voltages under 250V (I'm running a 120V, single-phase circuit in this case)?

Please let me know if I've left out any critical info for my install.  This is a simple branch circuit with a couple of 20A outlets in my garage.  Code citations are always appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The standard metal coupling suffice, if you install them properly.

[image]

This one is a compression style coupling, but the setscrew style will suffice as well.

You make the ground contact by running that conduit nut down and bapping it tight with a screwdriver blade and hammer... and tightening the compression fitting or setscrew.  After 50 years in a quasi-outdoor building, I can attest that it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

### You just need an EMT connector and locknut (and to make sure that there's no paint in the way)

You don't need the extra work of a grounding bushing for voltages under 250V, even when concentric or eccentric KOs are present, *provided* you're not dealing with service entrance wiring.  This is implied by the lack of a specific bonding requirement for such circumstances in NEC 250.97, and is spelled out in section 4.7.6 of NECA-NEIS 101, the Standard for Installing Steel Conduits (RMC, IMC, EMT) (parts not relevant to conduit-to-box bonding omitted):

> Metal raceways for feeder and branch circuits operating at less than 250 volts to ground shall be bonded to the box or cabinet. Do one or more of the following:
>
> • Use listed fittings.
>
> • For steel RMC or IMC, use two locknuts one inside and one outside of boxes and cabinets.
>
> • Use fittings, such as EMT connectors, with shoulders that seat firmly against the box or cabinet, with one locknut on the inside of boxes and cabinets.
>
> *NOTE: Remove paint in locknut areas to assure a continuous ground path. Repaint or cover any exposed area after installation is completed.*